# Identifying boxes with white space with open cv [Python]

Tags: python, opencv

Trying to identify boxes:

[image: Picture where i want to detect]

i want to be able to identify 3 boxes.
I want to know i have 3 boxe:

[image: Picture i want to get]

im doing an edge canning followed by  a threshhold_INV  before trying the shape detection.

im having trouble since there are white letters inside the box.(i think)
Can anyone provide a soluction or an ideal pipeline?
Thanks

some code:

```
edges = cv2.Canny(image,200,400)
thresh = cv2.threshold(edges, 177, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
     cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]

 for c in cnts:
   peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
   approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.04 * peri, True)
```

if approx == 4 it menas its a rectangle(i think)

Comment: could you provide some code as well? Did you try to blur / erode to get rid of the tiny white characters inside the big red boxes? and why are your boxes triangular shaped?

Comment: i did try blur but it got worst, haven't tried erode. Will try.
The thing is, if i blur   it stops distinguishing  gray from the red and  doesn't detect de lines of the rectangle.
And maybe my second picture is confusing, the arrows merely mean what i'm trying to obtain in the sense, i want to be able to identify 3 boxes.